# Set Div Position to Fixed When Scrolled to Position - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, position, css-position

I am working with a right sidebar that contains three sliders aligned vertically. I would like to have the sidebar's position to be fixed when I scroll down to 200 pixels. Here's my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.onscroll = function() {
        if (window.pageYOffset >= 200){
            $('.col-right').css({position: 'fixed', right: '490px'});
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing happens when I use this code. It detects that I am scrolling but it doesn't set the CSS properties to the "col-right" class, which is the sidebar. Am I doing this right?

Comment: Use quotes, `"fixed"`, `fixed` is

Comment: Added and nothing happens.

Answer (score 6):

OK, I figured it out. I changed `$` to `jQuery` and everything works. Here is my working solution:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    window.onscroll = function() {
        if (window.pageYOffset >= 200){
            jQuery('.col-right').css({position: 'fixed', right: '490px', top: '40px'});
        }
        else {
            jQuery('.col-right').css({position: '', right: '', top: ''});
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

replace:

```
.css({position: fixed, right: 490px});
```

with

```
.css({position: 'fixed', right: '490px'});
```

strings should be quoted!

Comment: Did this, nothing happens.

Comment: Works just fine for me -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pzNYX/), did you remember document.ready, as you're using jQuery to get a DOM element.

Comment: Yes, I added the document.ready function to the code and still it does nothing.

Comment: And you're sure `window.pageYOffset` is incrementing when you scroll, and that you have an element with the class `col-right` ?

Comment: The `window.onscroll` event is not working for some reason. The `col-right` class does exist.

Comment: You could always see if the jQuery version works -> `$(window).on('scroll', function() { ... });`, but that's doubtful. Somehow the scroll event is'nt triggered.